# HTML form field update on another field change

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I have a form that updates a total based on the field values entered on a form when the user leaves each field.
This works fine but I also want to update one of the entry fields which is a percentage of another.

I have in my js

```
var theForm = document.forms[frm];
var eTotal = theForm.elements["Total"];
var ePremium = theForm.elements["Premium"];
if (eTotal.value > 0) {
    var PremAmount = parseFloat(eTotal.value * ePremium.value / 100);
}
var divobj = document.getElementById('PremAmount');
divobj.innerHTML = PremAmount.toFixed(2);
```

Which is called with

```
onblur="addPrem('totals')"
```

The original value in the totals field from the MySQL table is 770.00
My php script produces the following html

```
<input name="PremAmount" tabindex="1" class="ent" id="PremAmount" size="2" value="77.00">
```

When I change the total to 888.00 I get the following

```
<input name="PremAmount" tabindex="1" class="ent" id="PremAmount" size="2" value="77.00">88.80</input>
```

So it looks like it's working but writing a div rather than into the field itself

Can anyone help me with this please

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the `innerHTML`, set the `value`

```
var theForm = document.forms[frm];
var eTotal = theForm.elements["Total"];
var ePremium = theForm.elements["Premium"];
if (eTotal.value > 0) {
    var PremAmount = parseFloat(eTotal.value * ePremium.value / 100);
}
var divobj = document.getElementById('PremAmount');
divobj.value = PremAmount.toFixed(2);
```